# Writing to a text file from DataGridView in C# windows form

Tags: c#, datagridview, streamwriter

I want to write the data from my `DataGridView` to a textfile.

The following code writes the data but it is not formatted correctly.

```
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(dirLocationString);

string lines = "";

for (int row = 0; row< numRows1; row++){
     for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
         {

          lines = lines + " " + dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();

         }

      sW.WriteLine(lines);
}

   sW.Close();
```

I want the output format to be like:

```
AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD
```

But instead it displays the following:

```
AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD
and so on..
```

Answer (score 3):

Init `lines` in first loop :

```
StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter(dirLocationString);

for (int row = 0; row< numRows1; row++){
    string lines = "";
    for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
    {
        lines += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines) ? " " : ", ") + dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
    }

    sW.WriteLine(lines);
}

sW.Close();
```

Comment: Cant believe I didnt figure that part out! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately looping through rows and columns is prone to errors and not very succinct. Here is a little hack that takes advantage of `Windows.Forms.Clipboard` and `DataGridView.GetClipboardContent()` to do all the dirty work for you. `DataGridView.GetClipboardContent()` returns all the selected data cells as a DataObject, which is how the Clipboard class is able to store different types of data and formatting. The contents of the clipboard are then written to a file using the File class. You say you want a text file, but I see commas the example of your desired output, so I am assuming you would like a CSV file. You can also write out a text file by changing the `Clipboard.GetText` parameter.

```
void SaveDataGridViewToCSV(string Filename)
{
    // Choose whether to write header. Use EnableWithoutHeaderText instead to omit header.
    dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithAutoHeaderText;
    // Select all the cells
    dataGridView1.SelectAll();
    // Copy (set clipboard)
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());
    // Paste (get the clipboard and serialize it to a file)
    File.WriteAllText(Filename,Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue));
}
```

Please note that an object must be serializable for it to be put on the Clipboard.

For a tab-delimited file, use the `TextDataFormat.Text` enum in your call to `Clipboard.GetText()`. You can also output your DataGridView as HTML by using `TextDataFormat.Html` instead of `TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue`, but there is extra header data you have to parse out.

Hope this helps.