# DataGridView exporter in C#

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview, export, streamwriter

I have a problem with exporting data from DataGridView into .txt file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace TSQ
{
    class TxtExporter : IExporter
    {
        public void Export(DataGridView dataGrid, Output output)
        {
            if (output == null)
                return;

            string filePath = output.TemplatePath;

            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
                {
                    for (int row = 0; row < dataGrid.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 0; col < dataGrid.Columns.Count; col++)
                        {
                            sw.Write(dataGrid[col, row].Value.ToString());
                            sw.Write('\t');
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine();
                        //sw.Flush(); <- also doesn`t work if uncommented
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I download a big data from database into gridview (over 350K records) and I try to export it into txt file, after about 200K of records I get "OutOfMemoryException"...
Do you have any idea how to export big data from DataGridView?

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Have you tried looping through your DataGridView and saving the contents to a StringBuilder(), and then using StreamWriter to write that string to your text file instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing to a text file from DataGridView in C# windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311535/writing-to-a-text-file-from-datagridview-in-c-sharp-windows-form)

Comment: I was trying with Clipboard but it works to slow and also causes out of memory exception :(

Answer (score 0):

If it does not have to be a .txt, try exporting to Excel instead.

Ref [How to Export DataGridView Data to Excel by using Excel Object](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-Export-DataGridView-62f1f8ff)

Comment: At this moment I have option to export into Excel - I am just using another class for this "ExcelExporter". But it takes a lot of time and with big data (>100K) it also causes OutOfMemoryException